# Unwanted feature: chat account auto-re-parenting

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, moderators

As a moderator on one site, it is kind of important that my chat account is associated with the site on which I am a moderator. Several times recently I've been booted out of the Teachers Lounge and other moderator only rooms, only to find my chat account has mysteriously changed parents.

I've finally made the connection that this is happening because I used the "automatically move this discussion to chat" link from comment threads on another site. Following these links seems to auto re-parent your chat account.

This is an unwanted side affect for me. If there is actually a justification for having this function, **can an option be added for disabling it?** My chat account parent is fine the way it is thank you :)

Comment: "The Teachers Lounge"? Seriously?  Does that mean you mod people consider the rest of us mere unenlighted students?  :P

Comment: @John: Actually we consider you all alien intruders, the diamonds denote the tinfoil caps we wear when out in public.

Comment: @Caleb Cripes, man. Don't tell *them* that! Now we have to do the cleansing ritual again.

Comment: @Caleb unless balpha beats me to it, I'll look at this tomorrow

Comment: That's a seriously strange side-effect.  Good catch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We now try to preserve your existing/preferred site relationship. If we can no longer *find* your association on your preferred site, *then* we revert to the site that was involved in this operation (i.e. what it was doing before this fix).

Comment: Marc I had this happen to be again yesterday. This time it happened when I followed a link from the mobile site to a notification in a chat room (Area 51) and my account re-associated. Should I open a new post for that case or is it related enough to just deal with here?

Comment: @caleb drat. What was the parent site before and after? (here is fine)

Comment: Before: Christianity, After: Area 51.

Comment: @Caleb thanks - that's useful (you see, Area 51 is a slightly different beast, with different handling; it is possible that the different handling has a bug somewhere - I will investigate (probably Monday))

Comment: Actually it looks like the whole problem might be back in a different skin: [Moving a comment chain to chat temporarily disables chat moderator privileges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113207)

Comment: @MarcGravell this didn't disappear...

Comment: @jcolebrand can you add more detail?

Comment: Hover over your last link.

Comment: @jcolebrand ah; the *question* did; it is deleted