# How do I invite someone to chat or send a private message?

Tags: support, comments, chat

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900198/any-idea-why-i-need-to-cast-an-integer-literal-to-int-here/7900249#7900249) I made a suggestion to @Jens Schauder to make a modification to their answer. I notice now that they have copy-pasted part of my answer (which I asked them to do) and have screwed up one of the links.

I would like to notify them but I don't think there is a particular need to do so publicly. Is there a way to do so, or should I just add a comment recommending the change?

I'd like to note that I wanted to do this because I have previously been given a notification to avoid long discussions in the comment box and to use chat instead. Therefore, rather than pollute the comment box I was looking for an alternative.

I also considered editing the response, but I do not have editing privileges and the recommendation is to only make **substantive** edits - fixing a link fell below my personal substantive threshold.

Normally in times  like this I ask "What would Jon Skeet do?" - but I don't think Jon has ever had the problem of not having edit privileges.

Answer (score 15):

In this case, I would just leave a comment (or edit it directly if you can; editing to fix things is not discouraged). On this occasion, I have edited those links in.

There is no private user-to-user messaging in either SO or chat (with a small caveat around moderation). Bad things happen in the dark ;p

Re *more general* inviting to chat; if a comment thread becomes extended an option is added automatically. Otherwise, you can just create a room on chat, and either:

- invite them to the room *inside* chat if they are already a chat user
- leave a comment on SO pointing to the room

Comment: Why have you added a winking, tongue-out smiley after the sentence, *"Bad things happen in the dark"*? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Kevin to get you curious so the [diamond alien people](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110188/unwanted-feature-chat-account-auto-re-parenting) can finish you off in the dark!

Comment: @John - [I am a diamond alien person](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/857/kevin-vermeer).  I was confused about why Marc, a fellow diamond alien person, would reveal this secret.

Comment: @Kevin Oh snap! Now you know we're onto you!

Comment: @John - No, *you're* onto us.  See you in the next dark alley ;p

Comment: @KevinVermeer As much as I'm sure I would *love* that, I think I'll be spending my next few hours warning the world about the diamond-mod-alien apocalypse.  In the meantime, I should probably get Jon Skeet working on a burnination-ray deflector sheild....

Answer (score 4):

Either add a comment (which you could later delete) to the post, or edit the post yourself. Someone with edit privileges should approve your edit. It is a small edit, but I'd argue it improves the post and should be accepted. You could also ask someone in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) to fix it for you.

There are no private messages on Stack Exchange (other than email, I suppose), and it's not really worth starting a dedicated chat room over a simple syntax error in a post.

Comment: Thanks, next time I'll do the suggested edit. I guess I was worried about the length of the edit, but adding two links is fairly substantive.