# When I bookmark a conversation in a private chat, who can see it?

Tags: support, chat, conversation

When we bookmark a chat conversation, the bookmark is saved publicly on our chat profiles. For example, [here's mine](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2562/doppelgreener?tab=conversations).

When I bookmark a conversation in a *private chat* to which only some users have access (i.e. the kind of private chat a moderator can create), who can see that? Can any user see that the bookmark exists, or only those with access to that chat room? If given the link, who can read the conversation and its messages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been doing some testing with other users. Here's my findings.

Conversations bookmarked from private chat rooms:

- will never show up in the Conversations list of a chat profile for any user, even the user who owns the bookmark.
- can only be read by users with permission to access the private chat room.
- *will onebox* if the link to the conversation is pasted in any chat room (even public ones) on the same chat server. (The three chat servers here being SO, Meta.SE, and the rest of SE.)

This behaviour is limited exclusively to the type of private chat only diamond moderators can create. The same behaviour won't occur for public or protected/gallery rooms.

Comment: Regarding point #3, I believe any link to a chat message will onebox if pasted in a chat room (on the same server?) as long as the user posting the link is able to access the room the original chat message is in. (I suppose that "can only be read by users with permission to access the private chat room." is also true irrelevant of whether it's bookmarked...)

Answer (score -5):

There is, generally, no such thing as a *private chat*. [Stack Exchange chat rooms are public](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/new); however, in gallery mode only certain people may speak.

Saved conversations are not affected by gallery mode, because you do not need to be able to speak in order to read. So, all your saved conversations from such rooms will be visible and listed publicly.

The only exception is for moderators ([moderators *can* create private rooms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143645/155739), which is why there are "explicit read access" options on the chat room settings page; I don't know why this is always visible). I can't test whether bookmarks from such rooms are visible to third parties, but I'm guessing not. If you've had such a chat in 2019, I cannot see it on the page you linked to, so that would be a confirmed "no".

Comment: "no such thing as a private chat" - wrong. There is such thing, you even mention it yourself in the last paragraph. Having this as first sentence is misleading.

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard "Generally" You have to, like, read the _whole_ thing..