# Moving a comment chain to chat temporarily disables chat moderator privileges

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, moderator-tools

I'm a moderator on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). I've gotten into [a prolonged back-and-forth on Gaming.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36714/in-skyrim-how-many-followers-can-i-have-and-where-do-i-get-them/36716#36716) (where I am not a moderator), enough to trigger the warning:

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

When I clicked the link, it—as expected—created a room, copying all my comments and the other persons's comments. However, I immediately lost access to the *Teachers' Lounge*. Upon further investigation, I also lost access to my chat moderation privileges.

Knowing [a similar bug with reparenting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110188/unwanted-feature-chat-account-auto-re-parenting) was prevalent before, I checked to make sure my site association didn't change, but it was still set to Programmers.

It was only when I went back to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) and clicked on the chat link there did I get my moderation privileges back.

This seems like something that shouldn't occur. What happened?

#### Update

With some more testing, I can do this on-demand with the link on the above mentioned answer. About 15 seconds after joining the new room, I lose access to TL.

However, it doesn't appear that merely clicking on the chat link on Programmers fixes it: I have to go to my chat profile, note that it still says Programmers under the site association, and manually select it again. Once I do that, I regain access to everything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have had other reports of this, and I spent a good few hours yesterday trying (and failing) to reproduce it on demand. The process you describe sounds subtly different to what I was looking for, though, which is encouraging.

Can I confirm: your site-association (on your **user profile**) was still programmers, i.e. that didn't change?

---

Found and fixed; while it was preserving the fact that you wanted to have prog.SE as your main site, it was still using `IsModerator` from whichever site was queried. Fixinating.

Comment: That's correct. Still said Programmers. I am apparently able to reproduce this on-demand with answer mentioned in the question: tried it again just now. 15 seconds or so after moving the comments, I lost access to TL.

Comment: I added some more testing to my question: looks like the site association *is* broken, but it doesn't show that on the profile. Manually selecting Programmers again, even though my site profile says the parent user is Programmers, fixes the problem.